# C# GoogleApi error - System.Net.HttpListenerException: Not enough quota is available to process this command

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm developing an app using API Client Library for .NET (`Google.Apis.Sheets.v4`), and having troubles with auth process. 
Code for `SheetsService` initialization:

```
private SheetsService __sheetsService;
public GoogleSheetsHelper()
    {
        // initialize sheets API
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        __sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        { 
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        }); 
    }
```

I've tested this code on two PCs, Windows 10 and Windows 7. There are no problems with Windows 10, but on Windows 7 machine I'm receiving such exception:

**Exception Text**

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Net.HttpListenerException: Not enough quota is available to
>   process this command
>          at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
>          at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener()
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>          at CheesecakeCalculator.GoogleDriveHelper..ctor()
>          at CheesecakeCalculator.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>       ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Not enough quota is available to process this command
>          at System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config()
>          at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener()
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()<---

Does anyone know what is wrong? Myabe need some windows configurations to solve this issue, or some other way to login/write GoogleSheets?
Thanks.

Comment: May be your request quota is full for sending free request using google api. Google provides limited number of requests per day. I assumed that you are using free service.

Comment: Yes, I'm using free services, but tests were run in same time, and on Win10 worked well after Win7 calls

Answer (score 0):

This is not a google error.

[Not enough quota is available to process this command.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms820778.aspx)

> Close some applications and try again. If you still get this message, choose System from Control Panel, then choose Virtual Memory and increase the size of your paging file.